# Karma opens local harddrive path instead of localhost

Tags: karma-jasmine, karma-runner

We use Karma (Jasmine) for unit-testing our application. 
I am the only one in our dev-team having the problem, that when running the test, a wrong url is opened. Therefore I cannot use the --headless flag as well.

Workaround right now is, to manually replace the url by localhost...

Hours of internet research did not even bring up one similar case.

Reinstalling karma did not change a thing.

Any ideas what else I can do?

[image: Image showing the url opened]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody else should stumble upon this issue, I finally found the solution: I had set an environment variable called "ip" pointing to this specific directory...